# UIWebView Current Link

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, uiwebview

I'm trying to get my webview's current URL by using the following code in `webViewDidStartLoad`:

```
NSString *currentURL = _webview.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

I set a break point and I found out that `currentURL` is actually empty. I went through the Internet some saying that you won't be able to get the URL until the webpage has compeletely loaded. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Try to  implement the following feature

```
<UIWebViewDelegate>
webview.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

return YES;
}
```

//get url from webView augment variable

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
 NSString *currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
NSLog(@"url:%@",currentURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the current URL of the webpage. You just have to log the request object and that will give you the URL that you clicked on the webview.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)**request** navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSLog(@"request on invite -=- %@", request);

}
```

You just have to use that request object and this will provide you the URL that is clicked.